# Help find component - MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, components, stepper-motor, component-selection, motordriver

I have a old motor driver board, for which I don't know the current capability.
So I tried to find the datasheet of the MOSFET on the board.
But without success (Bing search in various variants)

This are the information:

Package: SO8

Marking:
first line 2N604L
Second line 2 Mosfet is marked with 23D another 2 with 2AN
Third line 61744

No other markings or symbols.

Comment: But a quick google on 2N640L leads you to this: https://www.datasheetbank.com/datasheet-download/887256/1/Infineon/2N604L. Cheers.

Comment: Ok, seriously, never use Bing...

Comment: You are right! Thanks. Can you put it as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Thank you for your kindness and encouragement. So I put it as an answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question**

*How come I can't **Bing** 2N604L?*

---

***Answer***

*Perhaps **Google** instead:*

https://www.datasheetbank.com/datasheet-download/887256/1/Infineon/2N604L

---

***References***

(1) [BSO604NS2 Power MOSFET Transistor (Marking ***2N604L***) Datasheet - Infineon](https://www.datasheetbank.com/datasheet-download/887256/1/Infineon/2N604L)

---

*End of answer*